Excel 2000: find last row by year and cell location
A23:A1000: date
B23:B1000: balance (number format)
C1: a specific year (number format), say 2023

How do I find the value of B based on the last cell in A with year C1? I tried various forms of LOOKUP commmand with no luck.

How do I find the location of that cell?


Please...no thrashing that I still use Excel 2000.  :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To find the last value in a given year, you can use the formula:
=LOOKUP(2,1/(YEAR($A$23:$A$1000)=$C$1),$B$23:$B$1000)

Analogically, we will read the row number of this cell:
=LOOKUP(2,1/(YEAR($A$23:$A$1000)=$C$1),ROW($B$23:$B$1000))

We take advantage of the fact that error values do not interfere with the LOOKUP search, and if the lookup value is greater than all data values, the function points to the last one.


I believe you should clarify that this method finds the last row containing a date in the given year, which will only be the last date in the year if the dates are sorted numerically. Depending on the nature of the data set, this may or may not be important, but I think it is relevant.

Both of these work.
Say the first returns a value of 500.
Say the second returns the row number 495.
How can it return "B495", which I can use in another cell to then display the number "500" above from the first?

On second thought, I'm overthinking this.
Your answers are the solution. Thanks again.
